# Data structure / sorting for spatial data on slow IO device

Tags: c++, networking, data-structures, storage, spatial

We are developing a distributed software in C++ that has to handle a huge **static** file comprised of millions of BLOBs of data, each one identified by a unique 2D, 3D or 4D point in euclidean space. The size of the file is mostly determined by the number / density of points.

The file is stored in a NFS directory mounted in all computing nodes and must remain this way because of restrictions with the infrastructure. We also cannot install any third-party software (like a DMBS) or more modern file systems.

Each computing node will work on a "small" region of this file, determined by a box. The file is indexed so spatial queries are not an issue.

The problem is bringing the BLOBs from the file into memory, because they are not sorted in a way that favors locality or prefetching and we are observing major slowdowns.

Grouping BLOBs that are spatially "near" to each other in the file have proved to be a huge improvement, but the way we are doing it requires fine tuning several grouping parameters and is not feasible for the general case, so we though that there may be a data structure in which the grouping comes with the algorithm itself.

We found several data structures for accelerating queries, but none of them addresses, directly, the problem of storage, at least not on first glance:

- R-Tree
- Kd-Tree
- BSP-Tree
- Octree
- hB-Tree
- VP-Tree

Before we begin a process of evaluating these trees, should any of these trees be discarded right away? And is there other types of trees that may solve the issue?

Thank you.